# 'pip upgrade setuptools' reports success, but version remains the same - Windows 10, Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, setuptools

Using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10, in PowerShell. Without the --user option, the upgrade fails. With it, it reports success, but version does not change.

```
(venv-374-new) PS C:\Users\amir> pip install --user -U setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/b3/0a106dfaf7f48aef638da80b32608617cc8de4b24a22c8cd3759c32e5d30/setuptools-41.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-41.1.0
(venv-374-new) PS C:\Users\amir> pip list
Package    Version
pip        19.2.2
setuptools 40.8.0

(venv-374-new) PS C:\Users\amir> deactivate
PS C:\Users\amir> .\venv-374-new\Scripts\activate
(venv-374-new) PS C:\Users\amir> pip list
Package    Version<br>
pip        19.2.2
setuptools 40.8.0
```

Comment: The virtual environment was created with 'python -m venv' command

Comment: What is the output of pip list --user ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be cause of the way `PowerShell` actually invokes the commands at its prompt. Check the version of your real python environment. Then execute those command at a normal prompt, if you didn't have manually moved the virtual environment folder it will update and report the correct version for `setuptools` after updating.